# how to disable dragging behaviour for some of the sortable elements

Tags: jquery-ui

I have following `div` elements and I would like to sort only elements which don't have `class="nodragorsort"`.

```
<div id="1" class="one">
    <div>one </div>
    <div class="nodragorsort">this should be fixed </div>
    <div class="nodragorsort">this should be fixed </div>
    <div>one </div>
</div>
```

Am connecting multple divs using connect with in jQuery sortable. I want some of elements present in a div not to connect with other sort  divs and not even user can drag those elements those elements index should be fixed or need to make fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [items](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items) option to specify which elements can be sorted

```
$('.one').sortable({
    items: '> :not(.nodragorsort)'
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LNj7E/)

Comment: You saved me friend (y)